# Whom usage in sentence

Tags: word-order

> I am grateful to those by whom I am surrounded. 
>   I am grateful for the people to whom I am surrounded. 
>   I am grateful to those in which I am surrounded.

I can't get this to sound right to me this morning. I commonly use whom correctly, but have brain hiccup this morning. Please help. Tell me if any are correct or write it correctly for me, please. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to determine which preposition properly complements the past participle of the verb used adjectivally.

> We are **surrounded *by*** friends and family.
>
> We are grateful to those who surround us.
>
> We are grateful to those **by** whom we are surrounded.

We do not say:

We are surrounded **to** friends and family. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

We are surrounded **in** friends and family. <sup>ungrammatical, or marginal</sup>

I noted that **surrounded in** is marginal because **surrounded in** is permissible when that which surrounds is not made up of discrete individuals with volition and acting in concert but is an enveloping thing:

> It is surrounded in mystery.

Hearing **surrounded in** used in that way, some speakers might say:

> I was surrounded in people at the train station.

and mean not that the people encircled him or her, but that it was crowded and he or she was in the midst of the crowd. There were people on all sides. **Surrounded *in*** refers to that which surrounds as something inchoate, a mob or crowd in this instance, rather than individuals.

Comment: I would add that "I am grateful to those by whom I am surrounded" is grammatical but extremely stiff. I can't imagine someone saying this outside of, say, the most formal award acceptance speech.

Comment: @Mamster: I'd agree, but the OP's question wasn't really about register.

Comment: @mamster How would you say it in a way that is not 'extremely stiff'? 'I am grateful to those by **who** I am surrounded' would sound to me like an ungrammatical mix of formal and informal.

Comment: Active voice. "I'm grateful to all the people surrounding me." Or be more specific and say, e.g., "I'm grateful to all the friends and family who have supported me."